# vba - read text file, preserve commas

Tags: excel, vba

How do you read a text file with the commas included? For example:

Test.txt file contents:

```
item 1, item 2, item 3
```

VBA to read the file:

```
Sub readFile()

Dim sFile As String
Dim sPath As String
sFile = "test.txt"
sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFile

Dim s As String
Dim sFullStr As String
sFullStr = ""

Open sPath For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Input #1, s
    sFullStr = sFullStr  + " " + s
Loop
Close #1

Debug.Print sFullStr 

End Sub
```

Output:

```
item 1 item 2 item 3
```

The output I desire is the original text file contents with commas included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Line Input` rather than just `Input`.

This will read one line at a time; thus retaining the commas.

Also, you should use the function `FreeFile` rather than hardcoding 1 as the file handle.